# How to tell someone you are pregnant at such a late stage?

Tags: awkward-situations, acquaintances, approach

I am 35 weeks pregnant and I didn't tell an acquaintance of mine yet.

She is an old co-worker of mine and works a few blocks away. She quit working at the same company as me in January. She was honest about why she was leaving. Since then, I've gone for lunch with her twice. We don't text/talk regularly and last time we had lunch I was 20 weeks pregnant and I forgot to mention it to her.

Last time we had lunch I also mentioned to her some in-law/marriage issues so I feel awkward telling her that I'm pregnant now.

How can I tell her without it being awkward?

Comment: Have you planned to see her soon?

Comment: I was thinking of it, yes.

Comment: I've seen both extremes; where some spread the news as soon as possible whereas others haven't bothered talking about it until someone asks. How open have you been to talking to others about your pregnancy? With that in mind, are you concerned your friend will feel upset for being informed later than most?

Comment: Are you looking for the words to say, or skills to use? Is there a goal you have in mind, a particular reaction you're fearing that needs to be avoided, anything that makes this that you can't just tell her 'I'm pregnant, sorry for not mentioning it sooner'? Are you going to wait until you see her in person (when will that be) or are you going to text/call/e-mail her tonight?

Comment: I was planning to text. I guess I revealed some sensitive information about my marriage to her so I'm concerned that she might be unnecessarily concerned.

Comment: 'How would you do it if you were me' is primarily opinion based. Mind you that although a subjective site, IPS is still about [expertise](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), not opinions on how we would do stuff if we were you. As this question is having quite the amount of problems (a lack of detail, unclear what kind of skill you need help with, what is causing the problem and being opinion based) I'm going to single-handedly close it for now, to give you somte time to edit.

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing to feel awkward about. I don't know the reason why you forgot to tell her but you could simply tell her you didn't want to mention your pregnancy at such an early stage (miscarriages are still frequent at that stage).
You say she's an acquaintance and you haven't seen her in 15 weeks, so you're not close enough for her to get offended that you didn't tell her earlier IMO.

Otherwise if you want to use a lighter tone, you could still tell her when you see her stunned look when she sees you arriving:

> Oh, didn't I mention last time we saw each other? I think someone's in there, living for free!

I'd not overthink this. This is supposed to be a happy event, I'm pretty sure your acquaintance will be happy for you as well.